# Delete nth line (when counted from the bottom)

Tags: awk, sed, perl

There are unknown number of lines in a file. How to delete nth line (when counted from the bottom) with one-liner command (you may use more than one if it is necessary) on Unix platform.

Answer (score 17):

To remove for example the 4th line from the bottom using `sed`:

```
tac input | sed '4d' | tac
```

To overwrite the input file:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
tac input | sed '4d' | tac > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" input
```

Comment: Thanks Panki! However this won't delete line from the file. We need permanent change in file.

Comment: Use output redirection to write to a new file, then replace the original one.

Answer (score 5):

Pure `sed`:

- If *n* is 1:

  ```
  sed '$ d'
  ```

  This is simple: if it's the last line, delete the pattern space, so it's not printed.
- If *n* is greater than 1 (and available as `$n`):

  ```
  sed "
     : start
     1,$((n-1)) { N; b start }
     $ { t end; s/^//; D }
     N
     P
     D
     : end
   "
  ```

  Note `$((n-1))` is expanded by the shell before `sed` starts.

  This fragment

  ```
  : start
  1,$((n-1)) { N; b start }
  ```

  stores *n*-1 lines in the pattern space. If `sed` reaches the end of the input stream during this loop, the pattern space will be printed automatically (there is no n-th line from the end, no line will be deleted).

  Suppose there is more input. Then, before we get to the last line, this fragment is iterated:

  ```
  N   # read the next line of input and append it to the pattern space
  P   # print the first line from the pattern space
  D   # delete the first line from the pattern space and start a new cycle
  ```

  This way the pattern space is our buffer which makes the output several lines "late" according to the input. `N` from this fragment is able to read the last line of the input as well.

  After the last line is read, this gets executed:

  ```
  $ { t end; s/^//; D }
  ```

  When this code is executed for the first time, `t` doesn't branch to `end` because there was no successful substitution before. Such no-op substitution `s/^//` is then performed and the first line from the pattern space is deleted (`D`) without being printed. This is exactly the line you want to be deleted. Since `D` starts a new cycle, the same line of code will eventually be executed again. This time `t` will branch to `end`.

  When `sed` reaches the end of the script, the pattern space is printed automatically. This way all remaining lines get printed.

  The command will generate the same output for `n=2` (valid) and `n=1` (invalid). I tried to find a single solution that works regardless of *n*. I failed, hence the special case when your *n* is 1.

Answer (score 3):

if `$n` hold number of line to delete

to delete a single line use

```
printf "\$-%d+1,\$-%d+1d\nwq\n" $n $n| ed -s file
```

to delete n last lines

```
printf "\$-%d,\$d\nwq\n" $n | ed -s file
```

where

- `\$%d,\$d` tell ed to delete n last lines (printf will insert n)
- `wq` write and quit
- `-s` in `ed -s` will keep ed silent.
- note that no provision is made to  check you have enough line to delete.

sadly range **from end** can't be specified in `sed` ...

Comment: I like to add `-s` to the call to `ed`; quiets the output a bit.

Comment: @JeffSchaller done

Comment: Is there not redundancy in the first command? IOW, `printf "\$-%d+1d\nwq\n" $n| ed -s file` is legal, no?

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged with `sed` and `awk` but the question doesn't mention these as being required for the solution. Here's a Perl filter which removes the 4th-from-last line and prints the result. The output can written to a tmp file and then used to replace the original.

```
 perl -e '@L = <STDIN>; splice(@L,-4,1); print @L' ./lines.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `head` and `tail` to achieve this.

If the *nth* line from the bottom needs to be deleted

1. `head` reads from standard input and reports to standard output *total -n* lines from the top
2. `tail` reads and reports to standard output the bottom *n-1* lines from standard input.
3. Taken as a whole, the lines are thus reported to standard output in order, with the *nth` line from the end being skipped

This solution depends on `head` leaving the file offset of the open file description just after the last reported line - I believe GNU `head` does indeed do this when standard input is redirected from a file

```
n=200; tmpfile=$(mktemp) && { head -n -$n; tail -n -$((n-1)); }<file >"$tmpfile" \
    && mv -- "$tmpfile" file
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither standard `sed` nor `awk` support editing in place.

For that, you better use `ed(1)` or `ex(1)`:

```
printf '$-%dd\nw\n' 1 | ed -s your_file
```

Or with here-doc

```
ed -s <<'EOT' your_file
$-1d
w
EOT
```

With advanced shells like `bash`, `zsh` or`ksh93` you can use the `$'...'` syntax and here-strings:

```
ed -s <<<$'$-1d\nw' your_file
```

Notice that the `$` address means the last line from the file; so the index 1 there is **0-based**; for the 1st line from the end replace the 1 with 0 (`$-0`), for the 3nd with 2 (`$-2`), etc.

Putting it in a function:

```
del_nth_line_from_end(){ printf '$-%dd\nw\n' "$(($2-1))" | ed -s "$1"; }
```

Instead of `ed -s` you can use `ex -s` or `vim -es` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` cannot calculate nth row from bottom by itself, so we need to that before, e.g. using `awk`:

Delete 4th row from bottom:

```
delrow=$(awk -v n=4 'END { print NR-n+1 }' file)
sed -i "${delrow}d" file
```

Answer (score 0):

An one-line, in-place solution:

With `gawk`, this will delete the 42nd line from the bottom:

```
gawk -i inplace 'i==0 {if(FNR>t){t=FNR}else{i=1}} i==1 && FNR!=t-42 {print}' input input
```

The 42 can be replaced with any number. If 0 is used then the last line is deleted.

Notice that the `input` file is specified twice. This forces two iterations of the file with gawk. In the first iteration (`i==0`) the total number of lines (`t`) is established. In the second iteration, the nth line from the end is not output.

The file is modified in place by using the `-i` option.